# Opencart: Insert bulk products, product_id not unique

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce, opencart

i just saw some extensions from opencart that update **product from product list page**, i tried it my opencart project, intresting... now i started to develop a new extension for my opencart project that is: Insert **Bulk product** to admin... this can add up to 10 products one time, after fill product form just click Save button this 10 products can store to database... each product forms only with 5 following form fields,

- price
- quantity
- model
- name
- status

i can use opencart default product edit page for add extra details/option/descriptions later, and when insert this bulk product only 3 following tables connect with my query,

- product
- product_description
- product_to_store

I had tried some codes, my problem is when i click save button table `product` and `product_description` data insert function success, but `product_id` not unique from these both table, for example if `product` table `product_id = 125` then `product_description` table `product_id = 5`, i need these 3 tables **product_id** must be same unique like our default opencart insert work... any idea..??

what i tried here....
**Form**

```
<input type="text" name="product_description[<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>][name]" value="<?php echo isset($product_description[$language['language_id']]) ? $product_description[$language['language_id']]['name'] : ''; ?>" />
<input type="text" name="model" value=""  />
<input type="text" name="quantity" value=""  />
<input type="text" name="price" value=""  />
<select name="stock_status_id">
<?php foreach ($stock_statuses as $stock_status) { ?>
<?php if ($stock_status['stock_status_id'] == $stock_status_id) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $stock_status['stock_status_id']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $stock_status['name']; ?></option>
<?php } else { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $stock_status['stock_status_id']; ?>"><?php echo $stock_status['name']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

**Controller**

```
public function simple_pu() {
    $this->load->language('catalog/product');

    $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

    $this->load->model('catalog/product');

    if (isset($this->request->post['selected']) && $this->validateSimplePu()) {
        $url = '';

        foreach ($this->request->post['selected'] as $product_id) {

        $price_str = $product_id.'_price';
        $quantity_str = $product_id.'_quantity';
        $model_str = $product_id.'_model';
        $name_str = $product_id.'_name';
        $status_str = $product_id.'_status';

        $price = $this->request->post[$price_str];
        $quantity = $this->request->post[$quantity_str];
        $model = $this->request->post[$model_str];
        $name = $this->request->post[$name_str];
        $status = $this->request->post[$status_str];

        $su_data = array('price' => $price, 'quantity' => $quantity, 'model' => $model, 'name' => $name, 'status' => $status);
        $this->model_catalog_product->editPrices($product_id, $su_data);
        }

        $this->redirect($this->url->link('catalog/product', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, 'SSL'));
    }
    $this->getListbulk();
}
```

**Model**

```
public function addBulkproduct($product_id, $su_data) {     
    if (isset($su_data['product'])) {
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET price = '" . $this->db->escape($su_data['price']) . "', model = '" . $this->db->escape($su_data['model']) . "', quantity = '" . $this->db->escape($su_data['quantity']) . "', student_id = '" . (int)$student_id . "', date_added = NOW()");
    }

    if (isset($su_data['product_description'])) {
        $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description SET name = '" . $this->db->escape($su_data['name']) . "' WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
    }
}
```

thats all.... *above code only a structure*  If you know any extensions related my question, you can suggest me...

thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update Your model. Check the `/admin/model/catalog/product.php` and the method `addProduct()` - after the product is inserted, You have to retrieve the `$product_id`, so in Your model it should be like this:

```
public function addBulkproduct($su_data) {     
    if (isset($su_data['product'])) {
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET price = '" . $this->db->escape($su_data['price']) . "', model = '" . $this->db->escape($su_data['model']) . "', quantity = '" . $this->db->escape($su_data['quantity']) . "', student_id = '" . (int)$student_id . "', date_added = NOW()");

        $product_id = $this->db->getLastId();

        // INSERT INTO PRODUCT TO STORE
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_store (store_id, product_id) SELECT store_id, " . (int)$product_id . " FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "store");

        if (isset($su_data['product_description'])) {
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description SET name = '" . $this->db->escape($su_data['name']) . "', product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that You are not passing the `$product_id` as a method parameter anymore - the product gets inserted, new ID gets generated and for this ID the description is stored. Also, the product description is not updated but inserted as new, too! Product description is stored only if a product is inserted - it would have no sense to store a product description even there is no data for product...

And You should set the `language_id` for the product description row, too.

Comment: @shadyyx... you are right... i just miss it $product_id = $this->db->getLastId();  thanks for your answer, its work now

Comment: my above question everything i had tried done, success... but still no more idea about insert product_id to store table, my opencart have two stores also id=0, id=2... any idea.? thanks

Comment: while adding a new bulk product, You would have to get all the store IDs and store the link store_id<->product_id to the `product_store` table... The same way as in the `/admin/model/catalog/product.php` and method `addProduct()`.

Comment: I think You should try to achieve something on Your own. Did You look into the model file I'd suggested? I guess not. We won't do all the work for You - we only suggest solutions, advice how to solve and finaly solve the problems. This problem is only "I do not know how to do this" - well this is really a basic knowledge (`INSERT INTO`) and after looking into the model I'd suggested You should be able to solve the problem. If I write whole solution for You You won't learn anything... And the purpose of SO is to make people learn.

Comment: i can understand, but my question not about opencart default product insert structure, its totaly different from that, here when bulk product insert to table mysql query i can calculate, but something i tried for get two store id's from my form got errors, that why finaly i asked you a suggestion, anyway thanks..

Comment: Check my edited code - now the insert into `product_store` is added... That should be what You are asking about, right?